# SonarQube and Git integration

Tags: git, sonarqube

I'm testing SonarQube for several projects managed on Git Repositories. I created a shell script that runs the analysis from a CI server for every branch push. Ever new brach or merge is analyzed.

The problem I have is that is not clear which branches are adding the issues. In the dashboard you see the latest one that was updated only.

I want to know if it is possible to pass a parameter of some sort when I invoke the analysis, that will show the dashboard. I can send the branch name and in this way identify which branch (and users) is creating the issues.

I'm using the latest, Sonar 5.1.2

Comment: What CI server do you use (Jenkins/your own/other)? Are you using a git repository management tool like Bitbucket or Github?

Comment: Gitlab and Gitlab CI. But from the CI server I just run a shell script that ends with: `sonar-runner -e`

Comment: ideally I will do something like 'sonar-runner -e -name MY_BRANCH_NAME'     Assuming -name would be possible

Comment: Not familiar with those. I use Jenkins and Bitbucket server and I can create a webhook so that Jenkins is notified on every branch push, and the build displays the branch name and commit revision. Gitlab seems to offer this feature [Web hooks](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md), have you tried it? Honestly I'm surprised that this doesn't work out of the box since Gitlab CI is part of Gitlab.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My problem is that in Sonar I don't see the branch name. I can see it in my Ci server.   If I have 4 branches on the same project, all of them will be analyzed by Sonar, but I don't which analysis is which, I just see that 4 analysis were performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different dashboards for each branch by passing different project keys and project names. You can use `sonar-projectKey` , `sonar-projectName` and `sonar-projectVersion` properties in the `sonar-project.properties` file for the same. Alternately you can pass them a parameters in commandline.

For Example:

```
>sonar-scanner /k:"myprj-branch1" /n:"My Project Branch01 " /v:"1.0"

>sonar-scanner /k:"myprj-branch2" /n:"My Project Branch02 " /v:"1.0"
```